# uploading svg as stream using boto3

Tags: python, svg, boto3, digital-ocean

I'm trying to upload a photo to digital ocean. I'm able to upload jpg and mp4 but for some reason, SVG is not working.

```
  try:
        imgUrl = getImgUrl(tokenId, imgType)
        with requests.get(imgUrl, stream=True) as r:
            conf = boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=10000, max_concurrency=4)
            client.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=r.raw, Bucket=tokenId, Key=imgType, ExtraArgs={
              'ContentType': r.headers['Content-Type'], "ACL": "public-read"}, Config=conf)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e))
```

Comment: what is `svg` please ?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: SVG is an image format